# Didn't understand relationship error - Similar relationships, different behaviours

Tags: soql, account, relationships, sobject, person-accounts

We have two objects which has lookups to Account object. Objects are as follows

- Issue (audit_breach__c) - R/S name Issues
- Audit (audit__c). - R/S name Audits

[image]

Were trying to do the following SOQL on Issue object works fine;

```
 SELECT Account__c ,(SELECT Id FROM Issues__r) FROM audit_breach__c
```

But, trying the below SOQL on Audit gives an unexpected error;

```
 SELECT Account__c ,(SELECT Id FROM audits__r) FROM audit__c
```

Error:

```
INVALID_TYPE:
SELECT Account__c ,(SELECT Id FROM audits__r) FROM audit__c
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:36
Didn't understand relationship 'audits__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. 
Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Cannot understand why this behaves differently for the same scenario.

Can someone help to resolve this issue?

Thanks

UPDATE-----

Field Definitions;

[image]

[image]

Comment: Review the field definition of the lookup field. Specifically the relationship name and api name. You most likely have them wrong.

Comment: Updated the field Definitions, seems there is no problem with it

Answer (score 1):

You're actually querying the wrong table. `Audits__r` is the child relationship name that is present on the Account object. So in natural language your query would be something like

> Give the name and all Audits belonging to the Account with Id x

Which, in code would look like

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id FROM Audits__r) FROM Account WHERE Id = :x
```

Comment: I wonder why the first query works with the same scenario but not the 2nd one. Audits__r and the Issue__r are the R/S names but still lookup to Account.

Comment: The first query works because, in natural language, that reads, "Give me the id of account and the related issues of all the Audit Breaches". Apparently your Issue object has a lookup to Audit Breach object. You're actually querying the Audit Breach table, where you use the child relation ship name of that lookup field.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually using the relationship incorrectly. Audit object is a child to the Account. Therefore, when you use Audit__r, it should be used with the Account query. 
Eg: SEELCT id, (SELECT Id FROM audits__r) From Account

Easiest way to generate these types are queries with correct API names is to use the Force.com IDE Schema Explorer. Select the Account object and the fields required and then navigate to Accounts child relationships to pick the Audit fields.

I hope this might help you.

Comment: as a starting point I tried the SOQL(your Eg) you mentioned here, Unfortunatley this still gives me "Didn't understand relationship 'audits__r' " error.

Comment: have you tried using the Force.com IDE Schema explorer ? it will generate you the query automatically when you choose the child object and fields

Answer (score 1):

We were able to find the cause for this issue, we turned on History Trending on our Audit object while ago and this prevent supporting inner queries, Please see the issue:
 [Winter '16 - Didn't understand relationship in FROM part of query call after historical trending is enabled](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008ZqOAAU)